# ZSH ᐅ character showing as box with Powerline Font installed

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I'm seeing the following font problem when using the Oh My Zsh Muse Theme on Windows Subsystem for Linux. I've installed Powerline fonts which has made it so some of the icons are now showing but I can't find a font with the ᐅ character.

[image]

As you can see, one of the icons (the ✔ for the git repository) is working with the newly installed powerline font, but the ᐅ is still showing as a box.

I'm looking for a good way to search for fonts with characters I'm looking for or just a font that covers that character. I've been doing some research on it, and haven't had any luck. I've looked up the unicode for that character and using that in the search hasn't really helped either.

Answers to previous questions are great for getting the Powerline font installed, but it doesn't cover all the characters/icons that Oh My Zsh uses apparently

Answer (score 0):

I just changed to your desired theme and had no issues with my font DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline 12pt.

[image: screenshot of muse zsh theme with sejavu sans mono font]

I am unsure of how to search (and determine) if a font is compatible, I simply remember that this one was recommended on several forums.

Comment: Interesting, but for some reason on my machine, that font isn't working for me :( Not sure what the issue is

Comment: The installation of PowerLine fonts can be quite tedious in Windows, perhaps this [link](https://medium.com/@slmeng/how-to-install-powerline-fonts-in-windows-b2eedecace58) can help

Comment: Yeah, they aren't super straightforward but I got them installed. But, that's not the issue. For some reason with the powerline fonts installed, most of the icons work, just not this particular one.